# Atualização de campo baseado em validação de query

Tags: advpl

Eu criei um fonte pra atualizar um campo dentro de uma tabela baseado em uma validação da query, o pergunte funciona no debug, mas por algum motivo não passa pelo array, e também não atualiza nenhum registro, mesmo tendo 6000 para atualizar.

```
User Function IM06SCX01()

Private oProcess := Nil

    FWMsgRun(, {|oSay| U_IM06SC01()}, "Processando Registros", "Processando")

Return()


User Function IM06SC01()

Local cQuery    := ""
Local aCols     := {}
Local cAlias    := "SE2"

Private cPerg   := "IM06SC01  "



/*PRIVATE mv_par01
PRIVATE mv_par02
PRIVATE mv_par03
PRIVATE mv_par04
*/

ValidPerg(cPerg)
If !Pergunte(cPerg,.T.)
    Return
EndIf 

        cQuery := " SELECT * "                                                                 + CRLF
        cQuery += " FROM "+RetSQLName("SE2")+" SE2  "                                          + CRLF
        cQuery += " WHERE D_E_L_E_T_ = ' '  "                                                  + CRLF
        cQuery += " AND E2_EMISSAO <> E2_EMIS1  "                                              + CRLF
        cQuery += " AND E2_FILIAL  BETWEEN '"+  mv_par01 +"' AND '"+  mv_par02 +"'  "          + CRLF
        cQuery += " AND E2_EMISSAO BETWEEN '" + Dtos(mv_par03)+"' AND  '"  + Dtos(mv_par04)+"'"+ CRLF   
        TCQUERY cQuery NEW ALIAS (cAlias)

        (cAlias)->(DbGoTop())    

        Do While !(cAlias)->(Eof())

            aAdd(aCols,{.F.,;
            (cAlias)->E2_FILIAL,;           
            (cAlias)->E2_NUM,;
            (cAlias)->E2_TIPO,;
            (cAlias)->E2_FORNECE,;
            (cAlias)->E2_LOJA})
            (cAlias)->(dbSkip())

        EndDo

        (cAlias)->(DbGoTop())

        DbSelectArea("SE2")
        SE2->(dbSetOrder(1))
        SE2->(dbGoTop())

        For nx := 1 To Len(aCols)               
            If SE2->(dbSeek(aCols[nx][2]+aCols[nx][3]+aCols[nx][4]+aCols[nx][5]+aCols[nx][6]))
                    RecLock("SE2",.F.)
                    SE2->E2_EMIS1 := SE2->E2_EMISSAO                            
                    SE2->(MsUnlock())   

                    nCont++
            Endif


        Next nx

        If nCont > 0
            MsgInfo(cValtoChar(nCont) + " registros processados.", "TOTVS")
        Else
            MsgInfo("Nenhum registro processado","TOTVS")
        Endif

Return 

//*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Static Function ValidPerg(cPerg)

Local aArea := GetArea()

cPerg := PADR(cPerg,10)

PutSx1(cPerg,"01","Filial de      ","","","mv_ch1","C",06,0,0,"G","","","","","mv_par01","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","")
PutSx1(cPerg,"02","Filial ate     ","","","mv_ch2","C",06,0,0,"G","","","","","mv_par02","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","")
PutSx1(cPerg,"03","Data de        ","","","mv_ch3","D",08,0,0,"G","","","","","mv_par03","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","")
PutSx1(cPerg,"04","Data Ate       ","","","mv_ch4","D",08,0,0,"G","","","","","mv_par04","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","")

RestArea(aArea)

Return
```

Comment: Verifica os logs de erro, aparece alguma coisa ? Se sim, edita a pergunta adicionando o log

Comment: Só retorna : Valor de saída: 1

Answer (score 1):

Acho que o seu programa está usando o alias `"SE2"` para a Query ... o seu programa abre a Query de busca no Alias `SE2`, guardado na variável `cAlias`, mantém a Query aberta, e acaba tentando fazer a busca e atualização na Query, e não na tabela `"SE2"` real do sistema.

Experimente usar um alias diferente para a Query, e fechá-la apos ler os dados e alimentar o array. Então, selecione o alias da tabela `SE2` para fazer as buscas e atualizações.